# Wordpress: sanitize_title not working with long post titles

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this filter to set all post title in URL:-

```
add_filter( 'sanitize_title', 'wpse52690_limit_length', 1, 3 );

function wpse52690_limit_length( $title, $raw_title, $context ) {
    //  filters
    if( $context != 'save' )
        return $title;

    //  vars
    $desired_length = 100; //number of chars
    $desired_words = 50; //number of words
    $prohibited = array(
        'the'
        ,'in'
        ,'my'
        ,'etc'
        //put any more words you do not want to be in the slug in this array
    );

    //  do the actual work
    // filter out unwanted words
    $_title = explode( ' ', $title );
    //if you want more than one switch to preg_split()
    $_title = array_diff( $_title, $prohibited );
    // count letters and recombine
    $new_title = '';
    for( $i=0, $count=count($_title); $i<$count; $i++ ) {
        //check for number of words
        if( $i > $desired_words )
            break;
        //check for number of letters
        if( mb_strlen( $new_title.' '.$_title[$i] ) > $desired_length )
            break;

        if( $i != 0 )
            $new_title .= ' ';
        $new_title .= $_title[$i];
    }

    return $new_title;
}
```

When I insert a title with more than 20 words, it is not inserting all words in the title in the url.

Any reason why?

Comment: you might as well throw the blacklist filter out `$prohibited = array(` blacklists never really work.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this function and it works correctly.

So what happens is that your title exceeds the 100 characters limit that is set in `$desired_length`.
If you want to always have up to 50 words, you might want to increase the `$desired_length` to a larger amount - 500, 600 or something similar.

And have in mind that URLs must not exceed 2000 characters, as they will be refused by your web browser and will simply not load.

**EDIT**

Try changing:

`if( mb_strlen( $new_title.' '.$_title[$i] ) > $desired_length )`

to

`if( mb_strlen( $new_title.' '.$_title[$i], "UTF-8" ) > $desired_length )`

Comment: I've edited my answer - try forcing UTF-8 encoding when using mb_strlen(). See my edit above for what update you should try.

Comment: I guess something is missing - can you please provide more instructions on how to replicate the issue? Can you post the title that you're testing with?

Comment: this is post title i test  `مسحوق أوراق السبانخ يساعد على فقدان الوزن وكبح الشهية`